# 問うてはいけない？why not 問ってはいけない

Tags: grammar

I found this sentence from a Shinkansenmaster reading textbook.

> 基本語彙の語源は本当は問うてはいけないのかもしれない。

But てform of 問う is 問って right?

Please explain why it is used in such way. Thank you.

Comment: Did you actually learn the incorrect form 「問って」 someplace?

Comment: No. I haven't seen or use that te-form before, l'electeur. You don't use it that way right?

Comment: Right.  The correct form is 問うて.

Comment: @l'électeur The problem isn't that 問って is taught, I think (as far as I know, no one teaches that form).  The problem is that 問うて isn't taught.  In fact, beginners are often taught that する and くる are the only irregular verbs, so we naturally assume 問う is regular, and we're surprised when we find out it isn't.

Comment: Interesting.  One of the reasons that 問うてis not taught may have to do with the fact that it is rarely used in spoken Japanese today.  We mostly use 聞いて/訊いて instead.